# extracting data from database in xml format from textgrid format

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone give me some valuable suggestion about how to extract data from a database

in XML format where the data is actually stored in TEXT GRID format in database,will i

have to code in java or is there any other way

Comment: If you want to code in `java`, why this question is tagged with `php`.

Comment: well i am not sure....thats why i asked this question that do i require to code in java or php alone can do it..

Comment: Can we see an example of what the database looks like?